# Adding legend item for vertical line (mean) to already existing legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, density-plot

I am generating density plots like so:

```
# Density Plot ZOOM with no legend title and mean lines
ggplot(comb, aes(x=values, fill = type)) + 
  geom_density(alpha = 0.3) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(9, 15), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  xlab("Index Value") + 
  ylab("Density") +
  ggtitle(expression('TI versus TI'[u])) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=30),axis.text.x=element_text(angle=0,hjust=1,vjust=.9,size=20),
        axis.text.y=element_text(angle=0,hjust=1,vjust=.8,size=20),
        plot.title = element_text(size=40, face="bold", vjust=2),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=25,face="bold",vjust=-0.5,hjust=0.5),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=25,face="bold",vjust=1.5,hjust=0.5),
        legend.position = c(.87,.90),
        legend.text.align = 0) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('red','blue'),
                    labels=c(expression('TI '),expression(TI[u]))) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL)) + 
  geom_vline(data=mean, aes(xintercept=values.mean,  colour=type),
             linetype="dashed", size=1)
```

And that generates almost the exact plot I want:

[image]

But there are still a couple of things i wish to do:

1. Have legend items for the mean lines
2. Alternate the order of the legend items so the lines are grouped with the appropriate density legend item (Ti, mean TI, TIu, mean TIu)

When I try to just add the lines to the legend using show_guide=T:

geom_vline(data=mean, aes(xintercept=values.mean,  colour=type),
             linetype="dashed", size=1, **show_guide=T**)

I get this:

[image]

How can I go about doing this?

**EDIT:**  Using Peter's answer, I was able to get this:

```
# Density Plot ZOOM with no legend title and mean lines - double legend
ggplot(comb, aes(x=values, fill = type)) + 
  geom_vline(data=mean, aes(xintercept=values.mean,  colour=type),
             linetype="dashed", size=1, show_guide=T) + 
  geom_density(alpha = 0.3) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(9, 15), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  xlab("Index Value") + 
  ylab("Density") +
  ggtitle(expression('TI versus TI'[u])) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=30),axis.text.x=element_text(angle=0,hjust=1,vjust=.9,size=20),
        axis.text.y=element_text(angle=0,hjust=1,vjust=.8,size=20),
        plot.title = element_text(size=20,face="bold", vjust=1),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=15,face="bold",vjust=-0.5,hjust=0.5),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=15,face="bold",vjust=1.5,hjust=0.5),
        legend.position = c(0.15, 0.90),
        legend.text.align = 0,
        legend.box = 'horizontal',
        legend.margin = unit(45.0, 'line'),
        legend.text=element_text(size=12,vjust=0,hjust=0)) + 
  scale_color_hue(labels=c(expression(bar(TI)),
                           expression(bar(TI[u])))) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(title=NULL)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('red','blue'),
                    labels=c(expression(TI),
                             expression(TI[u]))) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title=NULL, override.aes = list(linetype = 0)))
```

Graph:
[image]

Only additional items I wish I could figure out:

1. Get the buffer around each legend to be enough to connect the two and make them appear as one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will be able to get the result you are looking for by adjusting the `legend.box`

```
library(ggplot2)
data('diamonds')

plot_data <- subset(diamonds, cut %in% c("Ideal", "Premium"))
means     <- aggregate( price ~ cut, plot_data, mean)

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = price, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_density(alpha = 0.3) + 
  scale_x_continuous() + 
  geom_vline(data = means, aes(xintercept = price, color = cut), linetype = 2, show_guide = TRUE) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", 
                    values=c('red','blue'), 
                    labels = c("Premium", "Ideal")) +
  scale_color_hue(name = " ",  
                  labels = c("Mean", "Mean")) +
  theme(legend.box = 'horizontal', 
        legend.position = c(0.75, 0.75)) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: That's very close, but not exactly what I want.  I don't want either legend to have a title, and need to replace the text labels of each legend item.

Comment: @traggatmot, I've edited the answer.  Is this closer to what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, much closer.  See my effort - editing question now.

Comment: A workaround for the space between the two legends would be to use theme_bw() or to set the legend.background to the same as the panel background, e.g., legend.background = element_rect(fill = "grey90").